# How to check in javascript if web part zones have no web parts?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

How would I check in javascript if web part zones have no web parts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a page has some webparts or not.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection/Default.aspx';

function updateWebPartTitle() {    
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);    
    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    this.collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();    
    clientContext.load(collWebPart);    
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.SuccessFunc), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function SuccessFunc() {    
    if (!collWebPart.get_count()) {
        alert('No Web Parts on this page.');
    }         
}    

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {    
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Check [MSDN source here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185010(v=office.14).aspx).

**Update:**

If you know the webpartzone id and try something like this.

```
<div class="inner"> 
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="zone1"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebpartPages:WebPartZone> 
</div>
```

then query the zone and see it has table element because generally webpart will be rendered in a table.

```
if($('#zone1').find('table').length != 0){
        //webpart exists
}
```

You may need to adjust your code based on actual dom.I can not test it now.

Comment: Its not about checking if a page has web parts, its about if a specific zone has any web parts using only DOM checking with javascript, and no ajax calls.

Comment: @omega then probably you have to inspect the zone area by F12 and check for descendant element length is 0 or not using js.And to me this will be a bad idea.

Comment: I need it to be in js, and was wondering if anyone has this code already.

Comment: @omega try the updates I posted.